# Cythonized function with a single positional argument is not possible to call using argument name

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

Long story short, I want to cythonize my python code and build .so files to hide it from the customer.
Take this simple function:

```
def one_positional_argument(a):
    print(a)
```

and my setup.py which builds the .so file

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='tmp',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    nthreads=3,
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        ["a.py"],
        compiler_directives={'language_level': 3},
        build_dir="output",
    ),
)
```

When I import the .so file and try to execute my function here is what happens:

```
one_positional_argument(1) # this prints 1 and works fine
one_positional_argument(a=1) # throws TypeError: one_positional_argument() takes no keyword arguments
```

There are multiple workarounds to this but I would like to know if I am doing anything wrong

Additional info:
If I have a function with 2 positional arguments, or one positional and one with default value, everything works fine. The issue is present only with 1 positional argument.

Comment: how did you get cython? PS i don't have a answer

Comment: I installed it with pip: `pip install Cython`

Comment: BTW, the answer is below given by DavidW, it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the `always_allow_keywords` compiler directive (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives).

Not allowing them by default is a deliberate compatibility/speed trade-off. However, in the forthcoming Cython v3 (the alpha version is usable now...) that will change: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3090

Comment: thank you so much. it worked. I couldn't thank you earlier as I didn't have enough reputation :D